# Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I don't use confluent, just use apache kafka, already add mongo plugin, get ... / connector-plugins response, list the MongoSinkConnector

```
[
{
    "class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector",
    "type": "sink",
    "version": "1.5.0"
},
{
    "class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector",
    "type": "source",
    "version": "1.5.0"
}...
```

]

when I use the following post I get the error:

Request:

```
{
"name": "mongodb-sink",
"config": {
    "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "portalesMCor.db_portales.user",
    "connection.uri": "mongodb://tiastest.mti:27017",
    "database": "Big_Data",
    "collection": "users",
    "delete.on.null.values": false
}
```

}

Resposnse:

```
{
"error_code": 500,
"message": "Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector, available connectors are: PluginDesc{klass=class io.debezium.connector.db2.Db2Connector, name='io.debezium.connector.db2.Db2Connector', version='1.5.0.Final', encodedVersion=1.5.0.Final, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/kafka/connect/debezium-connector-db2/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector, name='io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector', version='1.5.0.Final', encodedVersion=1.5.0.Final, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/kafka/connect/debezium-connector-mongodb/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector, name='io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector', version='1.5.0.Final', encodedVersion=1.5.0.Final, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/kafka/connect/debezium-connector-mysql/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector, name='io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector', version='1.5.0.Final', encodedVersion=1.5.0.Final, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/kafka/connect/debezium-connector-oracle/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector, name='io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector', version='1.5.0.Final', encodedVersion=1.5.0.Final, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/kafka/connect/debezium-connector-postgres/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector, name='io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector', version='1.5.0.Final', encodedVersion=1.5.0.Final, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/kafka/connect/debezium-connector-sqlserver/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class io.debezium.connector.vitess.VitessConnector, name='io.debezium.connector.vitess.VitessConnector', version='1.5.0.Final', encodedVersion=1.5.0.Final, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/kafka/connect/debezium-connector-vitess/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector', version='2.7.0', encodedVersion=2.7.0, type=sink, typeName='sink', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector', version='2.7.0', encodedVersion=2.7.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector', version='1', encodedVersion=1, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector', version='1', encodedVersion=1, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector', version='1', encodedVersion=1, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockConnector', version='2.7.0', encodedVersion=2.7.0, type=connector, typeName='connector', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector', version='2.7.0', encodedVersion=2.7.0, type=sink, typeName='sink', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector', version='2.7.0', encodedVersion=2.7.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector', version='2.7.0', encodedVersion=2.7.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector', version='2.7.0', encodedVersion=2.7.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector', version='2.7.0', encodedVersion=2.7.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}"
```

}

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar error when trying to use confluent's `S3SinkConnector`. Am posting my problem and solution here because this page shows up in the search results and there's a dearth of useful information out there.

Actually what happened is that I recompiled the connector after modifying its source code slightly because the original version didn't do exactly what I want. But then when I tried to start my connector I got the error message `Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector`. This is even though the relevant `.jar` is in my plugin path and I could see with `jar -tvf` that the .jar contains `io/confluent/connect/s3/S3SinkConnector.class`.

I was running out of ideas so I tried moving the `.jar` file into the `libs` directory of my kafka installation, i.e. into `/path/to/kafka_2.12-2.6.2/libs`. Then I started getting a different error message:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: io/confluent/connect/s3/S3SinkConnector has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

So the solution was to recompile the file with an older version of Java (specifically Java 8 using `javac -release 8`, as per [these instructions](https://www.baeldung.com/java-lang-unsupportedclassversion).) Now it works!

Comment: You are life saver for me. Thanks for describing your debugging procedures as well.
I tried to use a new Java17 JRE to run a old connector jar compliled by a old version. Your solution explain it well.

Comment: Exactly Thanks ..

make sure that connector is compiled with exact version of java where connect service is running.

Comment: Good idea to put the jar file in your kafka libs. The loading of plugins from the ${plugin.path} must have raised the same error. It would have been nice had the confluence developers logged it, because in the current version the jar is just silently ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error returned, you have the following connectors on your worker:

```
io.debezium.connector.db2.Db2Connector
io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector
io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector
io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector
io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector
io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector
io.debezium.connector.vitess.VitessConnector
org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector
org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector
org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector
org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector
org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector
org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockConnector
org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector
org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector
org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector
org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector
org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector
```

So perhaps you're running the `/connector-plugins` REST call against a different worker?
Or do you have a cluster of distributed workers in which the MongoDB plugin has not been installed on all of them?

Comment: But when you sent the class wrong:
 "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoConnector"

The answer is:
"Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoConnector, available connectors are: PluginDesc {klass = class com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector, name = 'com.mongodb.kafka .connect.MongoSinkConnector ', version =' 1.5.0 ', encodedVersion = 1.5.0, type = sink, typeName =' sink ', location =' file: / kafka / connect / mongo-connector / '} .....

Comment: @Alfredo As answered, it seems one worker has that installed and available (the server from that comment), but another is not (the server in your question). You'll have to restart the workers to pickup new plugins

Answer (score 0):

In you Dockerfile you need to install mongodb sink connector. For example like this:

```
RUN confluent-hub install--no-prompt mongodb/kafka-connect-mongodb:1.6.1
```